# How to save data in db

Tags: yii, image-uploading

In user table, the data stored in db as well as resize the images in folders.
But the usergallary table same functionality didn't work only image resized in the folders but not stored in db.

```
public function actionProfileImage($id) {
    $userModel = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $id));
    $userGallary = new UserGallary;
            $filePrefix = Yii::app()->params['profile']['prefix'];
            $targetImagePath = Yii::app()->params['profile']['image']['path'];
            $target150Path = Yii::app()->params['profile']['thumb150']['path'];
            $target25Path = Yii::app()->params['profile']['thumb25']['path'];
            if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_picture'])) {
                $handle = new Upload($_FILES['uploaded_picture']);
                if ($handle->uploaded) {
                    $handle->file_name_body_pre   = $filePrefix;
                    $handle->process($targetImagePath);
                    if ($handle->processed) {
                        $handle->file_name_body_pre   = $filePrefix;
                        $handle->image_resize         = true;                    
                        $handle->image_x              = 150;
                        $handle->image_y              = 150;
                        //$handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                        $handle->image_ratio           = true;
                        $handle->process($target150Path);
                            if ($handle->processed) {
                            $handle->file_name_body_pre   = $filePrefix;
                            $handle->image_resize        = true;                    
                            $handle->image_x              = 25;
                            $handle->image_y              = 25;
                           // $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                            $handle->image_ratio           = true;
                            var_dump($$target150Path);exit;
                            $handle->process($target25Path);
                                if ($handle->processed) {
                                    $userGallary->uploaded_picture = "{$filePrefix}.{$handle->file_dst_name_ext}";
                                    $userGallary->save();
                            }
                  }
                $handle->clean();
            }
            }
            }
            echo CJSON::encode( arraY('path150' => $target150Path,
                                       'file'    =>  $userGallary->uploaded_picture,
                                                                ));



}
```

Comment: Did you already use $userGallary->save(FALSE); ?
Check if you have validator for each attribute in you class too.

Comment: ya i have tried $userGallary->save(FALSE);. even-though the image doesn't store in database.. :(